# Transforming a polygon list after the cropping and resizing of an image

Tags: python, math, computer-vision, transformation

I hope you can help me with the following transformation I am trying to do in Python. Let me know if I can provide further info to improve my post.

**I am doing the following steps:**

1. Find the bounding box in a given image of size 1600x1000.
2. Expand that bounding box area by 20%.
3. Crop that expanded area out into a new image.
4. Resize that new image to 640x640.

**The problem I am facing:**

I have a polygon list of form [x1, y1, x2, y2, ..., xn, yn] that corresponds to the original image.

The polygon's coordinates do not only exist inside the original bounding box, they could be outside. The polygons are in yolov8 format and are normalized (positive values between 0 and 1).

How can I convert these coordinates so they fit the newly generated image, while removing any out of bounds polygons (ones that do not belong in the new image) ?
I have tried the following, but I think my calculation is wrong, or I am missing some center alignment:

```py
def transform_coordinates(coordinates, original_image_size, new_image_size, crop_factor=1.2):

    original_width, original_height = original_image_size
    new_width, new_height = new_image_size
    
    coordinates = convert_to_absolute_coordinates(coordinates, original_image_size)

    # Calculate the scaling factors for the transformation
    scale_x = original_width/new_width
    scale_y = original_height/new_height

    # Transform each pair of coordinates in the list
    transformed_coordinates = []
    for i in range(0, len(coordinates), 2):

        x = coordinates[i] * scale_x*crop_factor
        y = coordinates[i + 1] * scale_y*crop_factor

        transformed_coordinates.extend([x, y])

    transformed_coordinates = normalize_coordinates(transformed_coordinates, original_image_size)

    return transformed_coordinates
```

Comment: [mre] please. that implies data required for the code to run.

Comment: Hi. From your description of the issue it's a bit hard to understand what you've already successfully figured out and what you haven't yet figured out. For instance, how about the following heuristic: "If a polygon has at least one vertex inside the bounding box, then keep this polygon; if a polygon has all its vertices outside the bounding box, then discard this polygon." Then when you've decided which polygons to keep, the fact that some vertices are outside the bounding box is not at all an issue for the purposes of applying a translation and scaling.